# SQL Server 2008 Cumulative Sum that resets value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to have the last column cumulative based on `ROW_ID` that resets every time it starts again with '1'.

Initially my table doesn't have the `ROW_ID`, this was created using partition so at least I can segregate my records.

It should add the Amt + CumulativeSum (except for the first record) all the way down and reset every time the Row_ID = 1.

I have tried several queries but it doesn't give me the desired result. I am trying to read answers from several forums but to no avail.

Can someone advise the best approach to do this?

For the sake of representation, I made the sample table as straightforward as possible.

```
    ID  ROW-ID  Amt RunningTotal(Amt)
    1   1       2   2
    2   2       4   6
    3   3       6   12
    4   1       2   2
    5   2       4   6
    6   3       6   12
    7   4       8   20
    8   5       10  30
    9   1       2   2
    10  2       4   6
    11  3       6   12
    12  4       8   20
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
  declare @tb table(ID int, [ROW-ID] int,  Amt money) 
    insert into @tb(ID, [ROW-ID],  Amt) values
        (1,1,2),
        (2,2,4),
        (3,3,6),
        (4,1,2),
        (5,2,4),
        (7,4,8),
        (8,5,10),
        (9,1,2),
        (10,2,4),
        (11,3,6),
        (12,4,8)
select *,sum(amt) over(partition by ([id]-[row-id]) order by id,[row-id]) AS cum from @tb
```

other version

```
select *,(select sum(amt) from @tb t where
         (t.id-t.[row-id])=(t1.id-t1.[ROW-ID]) and (t.id<=t1.id) ) as cum 
         from @tb t1 order by t1.id,t1.[row-id]
```

Comment: Hi Nasser, this wont work in 2008. :( but this is perfect in 2012 though. :) thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT    distinct (T1.ID), 
                T1.ROW_ID, 
                T1.Amt,
                CumulativeSum = 
                CASE 
                WHEN T1.RoW_ID=1  THEN T1.Amt 
                ELSE  T1.Amt+ T2.Amt 
                END                      
FROM            TestSum T1, TestSum T2
WHERE           T1.ID = T2.ID+1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8b2a2/2

Comment: Hi Thanks for this, this is correct, however, pls accept my apology, I have updated my question., it should be: runningtotal = Amt + RunningTotal. I have updated above.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to create partitions from `R` column. First leave `1` if `R = 1`, else put `0`. Then cumulative sum on that column. When you have partitions you can finally calculate cumulative sums on `S` column in those partitions:

```
 ---          ---         ---
| 1 |        | 1 |       | 1 |
| 2 |        | 0 |       | 1 |   --prev 1 + 0
| 3 |        | 0 |       | 1 |   --prev 1 + 0         
| 1 |        | 1 |       | 2 |   --prev 1 + 1
| 2 |    =>  | 0 |   =>  | 2 |   --prev 2 + 0
| 3 |        | 0 |       | 2 |   --prev 2 + 0
| 4 |        | 0 |       | 2 |   --prev 2 + 0
| 5 |        | 0 |       | 2 |   --prev 2 + 0
| 1 |        | 1 |       | 3 |   --prev 2 + 1
| 2 |        | 0 |       | 3 |   --prev 3 + 0
 ---          ---         ---

DECLARE @t TABLE ( ID INT, R INT, S INT )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, 1, 2 ),
        ( 2, 2, 4 ),
        ( 3, 3, 6 ),
        ( 4, 1, 2 ),
        ( 5, 2, 4 ),
        ( 6, 3, 6 ),
        ( 7, 4, 8 ),
        ( 8, 5, 10 ),
        ( 9, 1, 2 ),
        ( 10, 2, 4 ),
        ( 11, 3, 6 ),
        ( 12, 4, 8 );
```

For `MSSQL 2008`:

```
WITH    cte1
          AS ( SELECT   ID ,
                        CASE WHEN R = 1 THEN 1
                             ELSE 0
                        END AS R ,
                        S
               FROM     @t
             ),
        cte2
          AS ( SELECT   ID ,
                        ( SELECT    SUM(R)
                          FROM      cte1 ci
                          WHERE     ci.ID <= co.ID
                        ) AS R ,
                        S
               FROM     cte1 co
             )
    SELECT  * ,
            ( SELECT    SUM(S)
              FROM      cte2 ci
              WHERE     ci.R = co.R
                        AND ci.ID <= co.ID
            )
    FROM    cte2 co
```

For `MSSQL 2012`:

```
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   ID ,
                        SUM(CASE WHEN R = 1 THEN 1
                                 ELSE 0
                            END) OVER ( ORDER BY ID ) AS R ,
                        S
               FROM     @t
             )
    SELECT  * ,
            SUM(s) OVER ( PARTITION BY R ORDER BY ID ) AS T
    FROM    cte
```

Output:

```
ID  R   S   T
1   1   2   2
2   1   4   6
3   1   6   12
4   2   2   2
5   2   4   6
6   2   6   12
7   2   8   20
8   2   10  30
9   3   2   2
10  3   4   6
11  3   6   12
12  3   8   20
```

EDIT:

One more way. This looks way better by execution plan then first example:

```
SELECT  * ,
        CASE WHEN R = 1 THEN S
             ELSE ( SELECT  SUM(S)
                    FROM    @t it
                    WHERE   it.ID <= ot.ID
                            AND it.ID >= ( SELECT   MAX(ID)
                                           FROM     @t iit
                                           WHERE    iit.ID < ot.ID
                                                    AND iit.R = 1
                                         )
                  )
        END
FROM    @t ot
```

Comment: Hi Giorgi, this is absolutely perfect. However, my concern now is the speed of this query as I am dealing with hundred thousands of records to compute going forward (64k as of now). Is there a more optimize approach that I can apply this to? Perhaps a stored procedure? I did execute the select statement and it is not yet done after an hour. I have to terminate the query.. Thank you for this though. :)

Comment: @Marian, I don't know about performance but you can try the 3rd example.

Comment: Hi Giorgi, Wow! This is beyond perfect, you have reduced 1hr execution to 4mins. perfect for my batch. Thank you so much!!